# How do I eliminate duplicates in this CYPHER query which returns all nodes with a certain label ordered by distance from root

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
START s=node(0) 
MATCH p=s-[*]->n 
WHERE n:label
RETURN id(n), n.property 
ORDER BY length(p) asc
```

Since there are multiple paths to n, I am getting duplicate nodes returned.
How can I have unique nodes returned?

Answer (score 5):

You can do return distinct.

```
START s=node(0)
MATCH p=(s)-[*]->(n) 
WHERE n:label 
RETURN DISTINCT id(n), n.property  
ORDER BY length(p) asc
```

If you're doing this, though... maybe this is better for you?

```
START s=node(0)
MATCH (n:label)
WITH s, n
MATCH p=shortestPath((s)-[*]->(n))
RETURN DISTINCT id(n), n.property 
ORDER BY length(p) asc
```

Comment: I tried both queries but they generate an error and don't execute. Thank you.

Comment: what version of neo are you using? they work for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Neo4j 2.0 this would be the best, or?

```
MATCH p=(s)-[*]->(n:label)
WHERE id(s) = 0
RETURN id(n), n.property 
ORDER BY length(p) asc
```

see: http://console-test.neo4j.org/r/2ae9x4

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even this query results in duplicates since my nodes have multiple labels and there may be an intermediate path leading to n:label from a node that doesn't have the label 'label'

Comment: When I ran your test query using id(s)=0 (on console-test) the 'Trinity' is returned twice. Query:
MATCH p=(s)-[*]->(n:Crew) 
WHERE id(s)= 0 
RETURN id(n), n.name 
ORDER BY length(p) ASC
Output is:
1 Morpheus
2 Trinity
2 Trinity
3 Cypher                        What query do I use so that Trinity only appears once?  Thank you.